# Automatic add-on domain creation

Tags: domains

I wonder is it possible to automatically create add-on domains (www.mydomain.com/first, www.mydomain.com/second...)?  I know it can be done in cPanel, but I'd like to have a program that creates add-on domains based on the user input.

Tnx, 
Stjepan

Answer (score 1):

In the examples you list, "first" and "second" aren't add-on domains or sub-domains, they are simply directories. So any script or program that can create directories in your document root would be able to do the job.

Comment: That's good. So, I can create separate websites in each of those directories and they will be independent of each other?

Tnx,
Stjepan

Comment: @histerius: Yes, but it depends on what you mean by independent.